# Video Stream of NSView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-streaming, video-capture

I want to create a video stream of a View in iOS. For example place a View in iPhone and draw something on it and I want to create a video stream (H.264 or MP4 or any famous standard) so that I can save a video file which contain recording of my NSView and all drawing and other operations that I perform.

Any idea where to start? Is there some API available in iOS to record video iPhone screen or a specific view??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2011/04/12/voices-that-matter-iphone-spring-2011/) contains a link to sample project that shows how to capture screen content on iOS and add it to an AVFoundation asset.
Download the sample project called VTMScreenRecorderTest.zip
Also take a look on the slides (the screen capture part starts at slide 44).
The capture code is based on Apple's [Technical Q&A 1703](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html).

Comment: It's important to not only link to articles in a StackOverflow answer, because the Q&A link doesn't work anymore